# Please help me avoid future violation of DRY principle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I know there is a much better/easier way to create an NSArray of small little NSDictionary objects, probably using KVC or some Obj-C 2.0 fanciness, but I couldn't find it and was just as well to type it up.
My class:
    @interface PDDetailShowModel : NSObject

```
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly)NSString *showid;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly)NSString *showdate;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly)NSString *showyear;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly)NSString *city;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly)NSString *state;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly)NSString *country;
...
```

The method:

```
- (NSArray *) createArrayForTableView
{
  NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSDictionary *dict = @{@"venue":_venue};
  [list addObject:dict];
  NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"city":_city};
  [list addObject:dict1];
  NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"state":_state};
  [list addObject:dict2];
  NSDictionary *dict3 = @{@"country":_country};
  ....
  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:list];
}
```

My end goal is to populate a nice UITableView with section headers. I got all this stuff from a JSON API call, but it's not in the order that I want for the TableView.

Comment: Why are you putting the dictionaries into an array?

Comment: What you have seems reasonable.

Comment: UITableViewControllers work very conveniently if you model data is in an NSArray.

Comment: `@[]` array literals? C macros are always an option too.

Comment: This is not only Cocoa touch but Cocoa as well. Not sure if other Objective-C implementations would support it yet but probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the dictionary literals in an array literal.

Alternatively, to avoid recompiling with changes, or to avoid unnecessary memory consumption, you can create a plist in your project and edit that when needed and simply initialize the array with initWithContentsOfURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"plistFileName"];

Comment: So I would put the properties of my object that I want to display in a .plist and then generate an NSArray of the property keys to use with Key-Value Coding?

Comment: Yeah something like that. As long as you know your keys you can use KVC. You can use the same keys from the plist to set up your data structures and then to set up any KVC based activities in a nice generalized way. It can help in decoupling code from configuration. The solution u choose will have trade offs always.